# How to insert a nested loop into 2 while loops

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, nested, sentinel

The following code below asks the user to enter a number. Then it prompts the user to enter more numbers. When they exit the program they display the highest number entered. How could I convert this code to ask for the gender of a person then age. So the output of the program would state the highest girl age is ____ and the highest boy age is _______? Right now its gender neutral and just complies the highest age.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

         public class largestNumb{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int highestNumber;
    boolean firstNumberEntered = false;

  int firstNumber;

      do {


     String firstNumberInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the           first      number: ");

     try {
        firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstNumberInput);
        firstNumberEntered = true;
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number! Please try again.");

                   firstNumber = 0;
        firstNumberInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number: ");
     }
  } while (!firstNumberEntered);

        highestNumber = firstNumber;

        String numberInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter another number, or Q to quit");
    while (!numberInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
       int number;

        try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);
        if (number > highestNumber) {
           highestNumber = number;
        }
     }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number!");
        }
             numberInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter another number, or Q to quit");         
    }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The highest number was: " + highestNumber);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

- You can ask for the gender in another `showInputDialog` method.
- Change the `showInputDialog` from an int to a collection of values, it can be an array with a length of 2 to store the highest age for the gender, it can be a map where the key is the gender, the limit is the sky
- You will need to work in your validations:

  - If you are asking ages, shouldn't that be stated when you are asking the data?
  - What will happen if the user inputs a negative number?
  - Would you accept an age of 1345 years?
  - What if it the text is empty, a character different to 'q'?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either placing another showInputDialog message within each loop or creating an if statement to specify the gender.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain two different variables which will keep track of the highest age for each girl and boy respectively. You do not need to add any additional in this case. Add code to ask the user to enter gender (validate the data) and ask for age. Based on gender do the separate calculation.

```
while(...)
{
    //Ask for gender and validate
    //Ask for age and validate
    switch(gender)
   {
       case 'M':
          //maleHigestAge calculation here
          break;
       case 'F':
          //femaleHigestAge calculation here
       break;
   }
}

//display maleHigestAge and femaleHigestAge with formated string
```